# Common variable for execution groups

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

If i create an environment variable will it exist in all flows within the execution group? I need to have a value which has to be shared between two flows in the same execution group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The environment variable has its scope set for a particular flow. If you want to share a value between two flows, either you will have to pass it on as a message or use User defined properties (UDP) to set it to all flows in the execution group.